# How to show a relationship between dice pool size and success probability?

Tags: anydice

I want to see a dice pool graph in Anydice, that shows a probability of at least one success.

Here's an example. There are several dice pools - 1d6, 2d6, 3d6 and so forth. A "success" is >=5. The graph should show increasing number of dice and increasing probability of at least one success.

Then I'd like to change the condition to "at least two successes" and so on. My final goal is to see a relationship between a dice pool size, success threshold and target number of successes to implement a proper dice pool mechanic for my little homemade system.

**What I've found so far**:
`Count` can count number of successes for a specific dice pool, like so: `output [count {5,6} in 6d6]` But it doesn't show a relationship between dice pool size and success probability.

Comment: When I come home, I will show you my existing program used for oWoD calculations. It does pretgy much what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use the [transposed view](http://anydice.com/program/ca47/transposed/graph) with a loop like

```
loop N over {1..6} {
  output [count {5,6} in Nd6] > 0 named "[N]d6"
}
```